# XML Namespaces with PHP's xmlwriter

Tags: php, xml, xslt

Firstly can you tell me whether this xml:

```
<adf:source xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.rightmove.co.uk/adf/rightmoveV4n.xsd rightmoveV4n.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:adf="http://www.rightmove.co.uk/adf/rightmoveV4n.xsd">
</source>
```

Is correct? I can't see how the document starts with: `<adf: source>` and closes with `</source>`, doesn't seem right to me?

I have replicated the structure using my own data but cannot get PHP's `XMLWriter()` to close the document with just `</source>` - it closes it with `</adf:source>`.

I'm doing:

```
$xml = new XMLWriter();
$xml->openMemory();
$xml->startDocument();
$xml->startElementNS("adf", "source", "http://www.rightmove.co.uk/adf/rightmoveV4n.xsd");
$xml->writeAttributeNS ("xsi", "schemaLocation", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "http://www.rightmove.co.uk/adf/rightmoveV4n.xsd rightmoveV4n.xsd");
```

and then eventually

```
$xml->endElement ();
echo $xml->outputMemory();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your XML is not well-formed. The root node of an XML document must be opened and closed with the same element. As far as an XML parser is concerned, `<adf:source>` and `<source>` are entirely different.

The `adf:` in front of the `source` element is a so-called *namespace prefix*, which is like a shorthand way of saying: "This element belongs to the namespace `http://www.rightmove.co.uk/adf/rightmoveV4n.xsd`".

So, the behaviour of `XMLWriter()` is to be expected and perfectly fine. On the other hand, an application that produces the XML document you have shown is clearly in error.

Comment: Thank you for that Mathias, I've been in touch with Rightmove, am hoping that we'll get some contribution from one of their developers in the near future. Your answer is, as far as I'm concerned, totally correct.

Comment: @tozjerimiah You are welcome. Please consider accepting the answer if it was helpful to you.